# Next cache problem. I change locale and try to fetch data, but the data do not change. If i refresh everything works fine

Tags: next.js

I have a slight problem that used to work fine. But on plesk deployment I suddenly have a problem.

I use cookies to transfer a locale value, that I know I always changes fine.

```
const getVillas= async () => {
 const cookieStore = cookies()
 const locale = cookieStore.get('locale')
 let url = `${process.env.API_URL}/villas?${locale?.value}&populate=details,facilities,roomtypes,bathroom,images,views,interiorImages,roomImages `
 const res = await fetch(url, {
 method: 'GET',
 headers: {
 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
 'Accept': 'application/json',
      },

  },
  {
 cache: 'no-store'
});
```

I have set cache: no-store.
Some of the translations that I have on the website come from a javascript file. When the locale changes those values change, but the api doesnt refetch the appropriate data in the other locale

```
'use server'
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation'
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'

export async function createLocale(locale) {
 cookies().set('locale', locale)
 redirect('/')
}
```

This is how I set the new locale

All the pages are server components. Any idea why this could suddenly occur?
If i reload the page everything works fine and i can see the page with the new locale